# How to run ChromeDriver requests in serial (not parallel)?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm currently using the following for frontend testing:

- Selenium 3.9.1
- Chromedriver 2.4
- WebDriverIO 4.12.0

The following quote is taken from the following URL: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2152#c9

> Sorry, I was not correct in my comments #13 and #14. This issue has
>   nothing to do with initiating multiple Chromedrivers with the same
>   port number.
>
> This issue is basically about multiple HTTP requests with the same
>   session ID which is not being supported in Chroomedriver and we have
>   no resources to implement this feature. Sorry about that.

My tests fail randomly with the following error:

```
Error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer (connect failed)
```

Does anyone know how to get these requests to run in serial and not parallel?

For those interested I'm running this on Node.js. But I don't think that matters.

Comment: Can you share your code that causes the exception?

Comment: @mosaad Unfortunately not (Would have to paste the whole page and I'm not allowed to do that). But the code includes multiple tags which I'm attempting to get via getText. This causes multiple http requests with the same session id which chromedriver does not support.